# How to fix the bug with connection to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have an html form and a connection to database, and when I hit submit button the information goes to my db. But if I refresh my page after, without pushing any button, the information goes again and again and again. Please help me to fix this.
I also would appreciate help of php form CRUD, from UI. Can you help me with code, let's say there are buttons, which show my database tables, where I can make changes from UI.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form  action="form.php" method="post">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Name:</td>
              <td>
               <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required> <br>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
             Surname:
              </td>
              <td>
              <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="surname" required>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

form.php

```php
    <?php
    //Create connection
    $servername='localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password  = '';
    $dbname='testdb';
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
      echo $conn->connect_error;
    }else {
      echo "connected successfully<br/>";
    }
    //post method
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    }
    #insert data
     $result = "INSERT INTO users(name,surname) VALUES('$name','$surname')";
     $show = "SELECT * FROM users";
     if($conn->query($result)){
       echo "data inserted successfully";
     }else {
       $conn->connect_error;
     }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: where form.php?

Comment: Redirect to the same page after successfully inserting your values

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Please try to use better question titles in the future. This issue really isn’t about any _“bug with connection to database”_.

Comment: Come on! Don 't downvote questions from beginners.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am a beginner, and everything I try to do is by myself. Thank you Marcel for your suggestion, I will try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for your issue.

1. The PHP approach: Redirect after the successful storage in your database. You can use the PHP header function for redirecting to another page with a success message.
2. The JavaScript approach: This approach is a little more cumbersome as it requires the data to be submitted using an ansychronous request with JavaScript. After the successful response of your script, you can then hide the form with JavaScript and display a success message for the user.

**Help for your CRUD system**

Since you have not come up with your own approach, you can not expect that you will get the exact help you need here. There are tons of examples, how you can achieve a CRUD system.

Here 's the basic approach of CRUD.

```
class Person
{
    public function create($name, $surname) : int
    {
        // insert data into database and return the auto_increament value
        return $id;
    }

    public function read(int $id) : array
    {
        // read out the data by the given id and return the data
        return $data;
    }

    public function update($id, $data) : bool
    {
        // update the database entry with the given id and the given data and return the response of the update statement (true or false)
        return $result;
    }

    public function delete($id) : bool
    {
        // delete the database entry with the given id and return the response
        return $result;
    }
}
```

This is how you should beginn. Then you have to deal with the data you need in your view. For reading out a specific person you need an id. For updating a specific person, you need an id. Same for deleting a specific person. Think about how to get the id. You can solve this with an hidden input element in your form or a GET parameter in the URL of the form.